# What do we know about functions that are like norms but only positively homogenous of degree 1?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

What happens if we generalize the concept of norm by imposing instead of the axiom

$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R, \forall x \in E, \|\lambda x \| = |\lambda| \|x\|$

the more general axiom

$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R_+, \forall x \in E, \|\lambda x \| = \lambda \|x\|$

In that case we do not have anymore $\|-x\| = \|x\|$ but what can we say? Has it been studied?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a function $f \colon E \to \mathbb R$ satisfying
$$f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x) \qquad \forall \lambda \ge 0, x \in E$$
and
$$ f(x + y) \le f(x) + f(y) \qquad \forall x,y \in E.$$

Such functions are called "sublinear functionals" and they play an important role in the Hahn-Banach extension theorem.

If you are familiar with convex functions, it is interesting to note that these are precisely those functionals which are positively homogeneous and convex.

Answer (score 0):

If $\|-x\|\neq \|x\|$, i.e. for example if $\|x\|>\|-x\|$, then $$0=\|0\|=\|x+(-x)\|\geq \|x\|-\|-x\|>0,$$ which is impossible.

Comment: The way you use triangular inequality in this context is incorrect

Comment: @Aristodog: Really ?

Comment: $\|x\| \le \|x+(-x)\|| + \|-x\|$ relies on the assumption $\|x\| = \|-x\|$.

Comment: @Aristodog: Really ? Interesting...